# Выполнить код перед отправкой страницы

Tags: php, ubuntu, seo, lazyloading

Собственно сабж: гугл добавил новый атрибут loading для автоматической ленивой загрузки изображений. Как можно выполнить код на любом языке, сразу после генерации страницы и отработки всего php кода? Необходимо вставить во все теги img этот атрибут. Тимлид сказал пока закостылить, знаю, решение убогое...

Comment: Сгенерированная страница и есть результат работы php. Не совсем понятен вопрос. Какой код необходимо выполнить? Зачем добавлять атрибут если страница уже сгенерирована и браузер пытается загрузить картинки? Даже если добавить их через js в onready это смысла не добавляет.

Comment: @Ajantiss тут как раз в том и идея, чтобы картинки не грузились одновременно со всей страницей, а подгружались постепенно, когда пользователь до них доскроллит.